# Adding strings as integers from two lists

Tags: python, integer

I have two lists. For example,

```
list1 = ["7","3","19","5"]  
list2 = ["3","15,"13","16"]
```

I want to add the these numbers together so I get another four numbers. For example the result of `7+3` and `3+15`.

My output overall should be

```
["10","18","32","21"]
```

I've tried using a for loop to do this however instead of getting `7+3 = 10` I get `7+3 = 73`. I have also tried using the `int()` method but I get an error.

Comment: So what error did you get? Can you show us that code? You have string values, so `'7' + '3'` is indeed `'73'`; the strings are concatenated in the same way that `'hello ' + 'world'` makes `'hello world'`.

Comment: Hint: Use `zip`, `int`, and `str`.

Comment: you are concatenating strings. You have to cast to int if you want to preform arithmetic operations

Answer (score 5):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), and [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) inside a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
[str(int(x) + int(y)) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Result:

```
['10', '18', '32', '21']
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your have lists of strings (not integers). `"7"` is a string. If you add it to `"3"`, you will get `"73"`. `7` is an integer.

The first thing would be to convert your lists into integers. Here's one way of doing it and the one I'd use.

```
list1 = map(int, list1)
```

This is asking python to call the `int` function on every element of the `list1` in the argument and assign the return value back to `list1`. Similarly for `list2`. Once that's done, you have two lists of integers you can add.

This can be done in several ways. I'd do it like this.

```
res = []
for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2):
    res.append(l1 + l2)
```

The `zip` function will "zip" elements of multiple lists into groups. So your lists would get zipped into tuples like `(7,3)`, `(3, 15)` etc. The loop with the double variable will unpack these tuples each time so that you'll get `l1 =7` and `l2 =3` in the first iteration and so forth.

Sum them and put them back into the result list.

There are more succinct ways to do this but this is clear. If you're interested, here's another.

```
[int(x1) + int(x2) for x1,x2 in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are concatenating strings.

Using the `map` function, you will get desired int list `[7,3,19,5]` from the original string list `["7","3","19","5"]`.

Then you can use `zip` to sum both arrays.

```
list1 = ["7","3","19","5"]  
list2 = ["3","15","13","16"]  
print [x+y for x,y in zip(map(int, list1), map(int, list2))]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ["7","3","19","5"]
list2 = ["3","15","13","16"]
print [str(x+y) for x,y in zip(map(int,list1),map(int,list2))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want.
First I convert the list into integers list. I zip them together and take each pair and sum them

```
[str(sum(c)) for c in zip(map(int, list1),map(int, list2))]
```

using sum is better than using c[0]+c[1]

Comment: Since the expected output is also strings, you could add a `str()` call in there. Also, why not use tuple assignment in the `for` loop? `for a, b in zip(list1, list2): res.append(str(int(a) + int(b)))`.

Comment: And instead of `res = []`, and `res.append()`, a list comprehension would be more compact and efficient and readable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I use sum rather than accessing the tuple so he might use 3 arrays

Comment: `sum()` is overkill for adding two integers.

Answer (score 0):

Iterative solution (*Python 2.x*):

```
from operator import add
from itertools import starmap, imap, izip, tee, chain


def pairwise(seq):
    a, b = tee(seq)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)


list1 = ["7", "3", "19", "5"]
list2 = ["3", "15", "13", "16"]
print list(starmap(add, pairwise(imap(int, chain(list1, list2)))))
```

Output:

```
$ python foo.py
[10, 22, 24, 8, 18, 28, 29]
```

Answer (score 0):

Function that could be used to add any number of lists.

```
list1 = ["7","3","19","5"]  
list2 = ["3","15","13","16"] 

def stradd(*args):
    return [str(sum(map(int, x))) for x in zip(*args)]

print stradd(list1, list2)
```

> ['10', '18', '32', '21']